# access the imageview from activity to fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-fragmentactivity

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have using **fragment** concept.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/_listDetails"
>

<RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:id="@+id/layout"
     >
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/neg"
        android:src="@drawable/a_pos_off" />
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/neg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:src="@drawable/a_neg_off" />



                       </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <fragment
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:name="com.xmlparsing.MainActivity"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1" />
 <fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment2"
  android:name="com.xmlparsing.SubCate"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here i have used **Two fragments**..They are ., MainActivity.java and SubCate.java

```
  public class AndroidListFragmentActivity extends Activity {

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
       }}
```

Here The positive image is there in fragment.xml file...Here if  i have to click these positive image which means the have to increase the text size for  fullcontent of second fragement (SubCate.java )...

How can i do ??? pls give me solution for these ...

This is my **Second Fragment** (SubCate.java) code:

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class SubCate extends  Fragment
 {
    int count = 0, i, j;
 WebSettings webSettings;
    WebView fullcontent;
     ImageView positive,negative;
    AndroidListFragmentActivity _listDetailsFrag;
    View activityView;

      @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  }     

    @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subcate,
            container, false);



    fullcontent = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullcontent);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    return view;

        }



       public void updateDetail(String articlefullcontent) {

        _FullContent = articlefullcontent.substring(1);
        fullcontent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
             webSettings = fullcontent.getSettings();


            fullcontent.getSettings();
            fullcontent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, _FullContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

      positive  = ((ImageView )activityView.findViewById(R.id.pos));
             positive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    count++;

                        if (count == -1)
                        {
                        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLER);
                        positive.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_pos_off);
                        negative.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_neg_on);
                        }
                        else
                            if (count == 0)
                        {
                            webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
                            positive.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_pos_off);
                            negative.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_neg_off);
                        }
                        else
                if (count >= 1)
                {   count=1;
                    webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
                    positive.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_pos_on);
                    negative.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_neg_off);
                }


            } 
            }); 
              }
            }
```

I have to run the app and click that imageview means the fullcontent text is not increase the value...How can i do ??? please help me and provide me some solution ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fragment can not find the corresponding ImageView. Edit to the next and check:

```
positive = (ImageView )getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pos);//use getActivity() Method
```